# Displaying Attribute in Product Listings issue

Tags: attributes, product-list, php-5.4

I seem to be having a bit of strange problem when trying to pull Attribute data to my product listing page. If I add this line of PHP:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')); ?>
```

I can successfully add the **Manufacturer Attribute** to my listings page however if I try the same code for example:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('model')); ?>
```

If I change the Attribute to **model** the code does not pull through the data for that attribute.

I find it strange how **Manufacturers** pulls through to the front end but **Model** does not.

It made me wonder if I setup the attribute wrongly so I copied all of the settings the **Manufacturer** attribute has and I still can't pull the data through.

Any ideas why this might be happening guys?

Here is my block of PHP:

```
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getAttributeText('model')); ?><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick,

This code is work if model attribute is enable in Use In product list.

So,go to `admin>Catalog>Mange Attribute>`  Select your attribute Check the **Used in Product list**  and  make it yes.

Then goto `admin>System> do indexing from Index Management indexing`

Comment: Thanks for this! What I didn't realise is that I needed to Index it afterwards :)